# MongoDB query is not working?

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, dao, mongify

I am using [Mongify](http://mongify.com/) to connect MongoDB and Play Framework. I wrote a simple search method which will help me to get the list of object after applying filter to it:

```
public List<Appointment> search(Long assignedTo, String appointmentType) {

    List<Appointment> appointmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    Query<Appointment> appointmentQuery = datastore.find(Appointment.class);

    if (assignedTo > 0) {
        appointmentQuery.field("assignedTo").equal(assignedTo);
    }

    if (null != appointmentType || (!appointmentType.isEmpty())) {
        appointmentQuery.field("appointmentType").equal(appointmentType);
    }

    appointmentList = appointmentQuery.asList();
    return appointmetList;
}
```

According to the method I am passing two parameters `assignedTo` and `appointmentType`. Now `appointmentQuery` will search in `db` and return an list of `Appointment` objects for which `appointment.assignedto` is equal to `assignedTo` and `appointment.appointmetType` is equal to `appointmentType`. But every time I am getting the size `0` of appointment list.

I re-confirmed the collection in MongoDB and it's present. What I am doing wrong here? Do I need to apply `filter`?